# How are shared libraries safe from exploitation?

Tags: c++, c, linker, operating-system, exploit

I'm trying to understand how shared/dynamic libraries work. I think I have a general grasp but I'm having trouble understanding how they are protected against exploits.

If a program uses a shared library, I understand that it is linked at execution. So the linker resolves all the missing symbols to their respective libraries.

When the shared library's function is actually called, it's my understanding that the execution jumps into the shared library's executable.

This is where my confusion comes from. Couldn't one just specify the address to jump to by "guessing" in order to call private methods in the library and possibly gain escalated privileges?

I appreciate any help with understanding this better. Thanks

Comment: _"... gain escalated privileges?"_ no the shared library runs under the same rights as the main program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes.  The program that starts the process owns the address space and can do whatever it likes.  If your library has dangerous interactions with another process with more privileges that can lead to escalation, the other process needs its own defenses.  Nothing prevents somebody from calling private methods or static functions in your library at all, and any method that might do could be circumvented.

Answer (score 1):

> Couldn't one just specify the address to jump to by "guessing" in
>   order to call private methods

Yes. But, if you don't trust the program, there are much worse things it could do. Simple solution: Do not execute programs you are not trusting.

> and possibly gain escalated privileges?

No. A library used by a process doesn't have more privileges than the process itself.

Answer (score -1):

Of course this is possible, but there are mechanisms like ASLR, which impede any 'guessing'-method. Further, there is paging, which inhibits user-code from manipulating and executing the kernel's data and code, if you're talking about privilege escalation within the scope of operating systems.

Comment: ASLR won't stop a process from accessing it's own legitimate library (including its content). Neither will paging and/or executable markers (which are not exactly the same thing)

Answer (score -1):

Folks brought up in the eunuchs and windoze worlds have missed out on better designed systems. There are systems that explicitly manage shared libraries in order to cut down on their exploited. Such shared libraries would be INSTALLED by the system. In fact, the same installation would be used for programs to have elevated privilege. For example, a benign program like a process monitor that requires access to kernel data could be installed with privileges that the user would not have on his own.

Comment: a) How about naming such a system? b) How about writing understandable sentences ("in order to cut down on their exploited") in an approriate tone ("eunuchs and windoze")? c) How is this **any** different from Unix&co and Windows? Running some programs with different privileges than the user has is exactly what they do.